# In Latex, how to have a multiline block contained into one enumerate item?

Tags: algorithms, algpseudocode

In Latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{example}
\author{ }
\date{October 2022}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
    
            \State $InvariantList \gets FD(PDDL)$
            \State $StateVar \gets StateVar(LatPlan)$
            
            \While{$InvariantList \neq $ $\emptyset$}
                \State 
                    \begin{enumerate}
                        \item \textit{Inv} = $highInv($InvariantList) 
                        \item Train LatPlan by enforcing \textit{Inv}
                        \item  $StateVarTmp \gets StateVar(LatPlan)$ \\ \If{$StateVarTmp <    $ StateVar} \State Keep Inv in the loss function and in InvariantList\Else \State Discard Inv from the loss function and from InvariantList \EndIf
                        \item other item
                    \end{enumerate}
                    
            \EndWhile
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Which do not render what I am expecting, which is:

[image]

I.e., I want to remove the numbers for the "If" block, since I want this block to be part of the 3rd item.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

With the package enumitem and a bit of DIY

- \setlist{nosep}

  ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{algorithm}
   \usepackage{algpseudocode}
   \usepackage{enumitem}

   \begin{document}
   \setlist{nosep}
   \begin{algorithm}
   \begin{algorithmic}
       \State $InvariantList \gets FD(PDDL)$
       \State $StateVar \gets StateVar(LatPlan)$
       \While{$InvariantList \neq $ $\emptyset$}
           \State              
               \begin{enumerate}\vspace{-1\baselineskip}
                   \item \textit{Inv} = $highInv($InvariantList) 
                   \item Train LatPlan by enforcing \textit{Inv}
                   \item  
                   $StateVarTmp \gets StateVar(LatPlan)$
               \end{enumerate}
               \begin{itemize}[label =]\vspace{-1.\baselineskip}
                   \item\If{$StateVarTmp <    $ StateVar} \State Keep Inv in the loss function and in InvariantList\Else \State Discard Inv from the loss function and from InvariantList \EndIf
               \end{itemize}
                   \begin{enumerate}[resume]
               \item other item
               \end{enumerate} 
       \EndWhile         
   \end{algorithmic}
   \end{algorithm}
   \end{document}
  ```

[image]